# How does the slow All-pairs-shortest-paths algorithm work?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path

I am trying to fully understand the following algorithm from CLRS book:

[image]
[image]

I like to think that it works similarly to Bellman-Ford algorithm by relaxing all edges once for every vertex in the graph. Then we repeat the process for every source vertex $s \in V$. But then looking at the three nested loops in `EXTEND-SHORTEST-PATHS` and the additional loop in `SLOW-ALL-PAIRS-SHORTEST-PATHS` I am confused what is happening in every loop. The book says that in every iteration of the loop in `SLOW-ALL-PAIRS-SHORTEST-PATHS` it computes a matrix of size at most $m$ edges which confuses me even more.

Could someone please explain in simple terms how the algorithm works? Also in line 7 in `EXTEND-SHORTEST-PATHS` does it mean:
$$l^{'}_{ij} > l_{ik} + w_{kj} \Rightarrow l^{'}_{ij} = l_{ik} + w_{kj}$$
or
$$l^{'}_{ij} >= l_{ik} + w_{kj} \Rightarrow l^{'}_{ij} = l_{ik} + w_{kj}$$
While there might not be a difference in both of these cases on computing shortest path distances, it does, however, produce different results when computing predecessor-subgraph.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This algorithm is slower than running Bellman-Ford $n$ times, one per source. Single instance of Bellman-Ford has complexity $O(|V| |E|)$ (on dense graphs this is equivalent to $O(|V|^3)$.

Comment: This algorithm indeed is running Bellman-Ford from all sources in parallel. If you have calculated all shortest path that uses $t$ edges, after executing `Extend-shortest-path` you have all shortest path that uses $t+1$ edges.

Comment: If we run bellman-ford $n=|V|$ times, the running time would be $O(V^2E)$ which is $O(V^4)$ for dense graphs. I can't wrap my mind around those loops, although, i too think so that it's running bellman-ford in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me tell you what Bellman-Fords is actually doing because the sentence `by relaxing all edges once for every vertex in the graph` is not very accurate. In Bellman-Ford you care about single-source-shortest-path. Since every path in the graph have at most $n$ nodes it has at most $n-1$ edges.

Let's say the source node is $s$, then create a table $distance[\cdot]$ such that $distance[s] = 0$ and it is $\infty$ elsewhere. Let's solve the following dynamic programming problem, compute shortest path from $s$ to $u$ (for every $u$) that uses at at least $t$ edges.

The table we already filled is correct for the case of $t=0$. If you have this table already computed for some $t$ after relaxing all edges (in any order) it will be correct for $t+1$, since you extend all shortest path that uses $t$ edges with at least one more edge by relaxing the end of the path. Notice that you don't need to relax every edge $n$ times, but $n - 1$ times since largest path will have at most $n - 1$ edges.

The algorithm you showed is doing that for every pair of nodes in parallel. The first loop only runs $n - 2$ (instead of $n - 1$ times as I stated above) because you started with a matrix with all shortest path of length 1 already calculated (your base case is $t = 1$ instead of $t = 0$).

First loop of `Extend-shortest-path` is selecting the source node and following two loops are iterating through all edges (it assume the graph is complete) and relax the path that starts at $i$ ends in $j$ and use the edge $j-k$ next.

---

Old answer below (I miss-read the question and assumed it was asking  about Floyd-Warshall)

The key element that makes [Floyd-Warshall (All-pairs-shortest-path)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) works is very different from Bellman-Fords key element.

Floyd-Warshall solves the following problem using dynamic programming. Calculate shortest path from every pair of vertex that use only first `k` vertex as intermediate hops. At the beginning it is the initial weight of existing edges and $\infty$ elsewhere (That is the base case).

Assume you have calculated such matrix for the first $k$ vertex and let's try to compute it for the first $k+1$ vertex. We should take into account paths that uses first $k$ vertex and goes through vertex $k+1$. Denote by $dp_k(u, v)$ the shortest path from $u$ to $v$ using first $k$ vertex, then it follows that the optimal path from $u$ to $v$ using $k+1$ vertex don't use this new vertex or indeed use it, so we get minimum from both values:

$$dp_{k+1}(u, v) = min(dp_k(u, v), dp(u, k) + dp(k, v))$$

In practice, the same table is reused on every step, so the algorithm only requires $O(n^2)$ spatial complexity. Temporal complexity is $O(n^3)$.

Comment: The algorithm in my question is not Floyd-Warshall.

Comment: I see, sorry for answering without fully understand your question.

Comment: @razzak I updated the answer with real question in mind. Hope it helps now.